# Sum distribution of independent normal variables

Tags: r, probability, distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose I have products A, B and C with the following weight distributions:

A~N(5,2)
B~N(10,4)
C~N(8, 9)

Suppose a car is loaded with 5 units of A, 3 units of B, and 4 units of C.

Suppose further that the car weighs 600 kg.

What is the distribution of the car's total weight?

I tried to solve it as follows, but I don't know if it's correct:

Let X be the total weight:
X = 5A + 3B + 4C + 600

E(X) = E(5A + 3B + 4C + 600) = 5E(A) + 3E(B) + 4E(C) + E(600)
= 5x5 + 3x10 + 4x8 + 600 = 687 kg

Var(X) = Var(5A + 3B + 4C + 600) = 5²xVar(A) + 3²xVar(B) + 4²xVar(C) + Var(600)
= 25x2 + 9x4 + 16x9 + 0 = 230 kg²

Is this right? I'm trying to do simulations in Software R, but I don't get these values.

I want to calculate the probability that the total weight is greater than 680kg. My script in R. :

```
total_w<-c()
for (i in 1:10000){
  a <- rnorm(5,5,sd = sqrt(2))
  b <- rnorm(3,10,sd = sqrt(4))
  c <- rnorm(4,8,sd = sqrt(9))
  total_w[i] <- sum(a)+sum(b)+sum(c)+600
}

sum(total_w>680)/10000
```

I was hoping to get to a simulation where it would result in the same value as this:

```
pnorm(680, 687, sqrt(230), lower.tail = F)
```

Comment: Your variance calculation is incorrect.  The mistake lies in replacing five independent versions of $A$ (*etc*) with a multiple $5A.$  In `R`, your mathematics corresponds to `a <- 5 * rnorm(1,5,sqrt(2))` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are correct.

With the following code to simulate this data I get approximately what you got analytically:

```r
a <- rnorm(10000, 5, sqrt(2))
b <- rnorm(10000, 10, sqrt(4))
c <- rnorm(10000, 8, sqrt(9))
w <- 600
t <- 5*a + 3*b + 4*c + w

mean(t) # approx. 687
var(t) # approx. 230
```

I imagine where you have gone wrong is in not realising that `rnorm` expects the standard deviation of the normal distribution, rather than its variance.

Comment: I think my mistake is in the simulation then.
I'm mixing "average distribution" with "total distribution". I added the code in the question, can you take a look?

Comment: The idea in my code was to take 5 elements from A, 3 from B and 4 from C. Add their values and add 600kg. I repeat this 10 thousand times and check in how many of them the sum of the weights is greater than 680kg. In the end, what I really want is to calculate the probability that the total weight will exceed 680kg.

Comment: This code does not correctly answer the original exercise.  "5 units of A" is intended to mean five *independent* weights drawn from distribution A, as implemented in the OP's code.